# Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57519', transport: 'socket' IntelliJ

Tags: grails, virtual-machine

I dont have any idea what is wrong. This is what the console shows:

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 57519

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57519', transport: 'socket'
|Loading Grails 2.2.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
.............
|Running Grails application
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/name
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57519', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0

Anyone can help?

Comment: Does a problem also occur if you simply run `grails run-app` without debugging options?

Comment: Moreover did check out a stacktrace? Probably an error is thrown which leads to stopping the app.

Answer (score 0):

Check your profiles are properly configured and logback.xml contains the default profile configuration.

For example: If your application.properties or application.yml contains

## Applicaiton wide technical configuration

spring:

profiles:

```
active: uat
```

**then your logback.xml must contain:**

```
<springProfile name="uat">
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="./logs/app.log"/>
  .....

</springProfile>
```